# IPSEC End to End Tunnel Throughput

Tags: linux, ipsec

I have established a IPSEC tunnel ( standard configuration , with ESP) , on two Linux machines (centos6 , core i7) communicating over 1 gbps LAN , and i'am checking the communication throughput. It never goes higher than 400 MBps.

Is there any parallel implementation of IPSEC, that can utilize all the cores of the machine and increase the throughput?

Comment: Are you sure IPsec is the bottleneck ?

Comment: Yes , without using the IPSEC tunnel  i.e plaintext , its around 800 mbps

Comment: Encryption isn't supposed to be parallelized.  There are some white papers on embedded proposals/implementations, but not for standard Linux.  I'm surprised at how much of a slowdown you're seeing.  I wouldn't expect half.

Comment: I guess it depends on how fast the CPU can encrypt data on one end, and how fast the other CPU can decrypt data on the other end, I suggest attempting some benchmarks on both systems and see how much data can you encrypt/decrypt per second, I think that's your bottleneck, based on this, you can pick the algorithm that suits you better

Comment: By CPU , you mean just one core , or all the cores? i don't know how ipsec uses the cores. It just run on one core or all the cores?

Comment: I mean, how much data can the CPU encrypt/decrypt in a given timeframe, I (just)assume that it's using only one core, since you're sending one large piece of data, being encrypted, it cannot be compressed, however, it could technically use multiple threads and split the data into chunks, but that would be optimization for JUST the use case you present, last I checked, TrueCrypt was able to encrypt data using AES-256 at around 3XX MO/s, so, your 400MO/s is pretty accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any parallel implementation of IPSEC that can utilize all the cores of the machine and increase the throughput. ?

I don't think that current implementations will encrypt data from the same data stream (connection) in parallel and it would only possible for selected ciphers anyway. That means it would not be possible for [CBC ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) since the encryption of one block depends on the encryption of the previous block.

But you could of course have multiple data streams (i.e. connections) in parallel and in this case the encryption of these streams will be done in parallel too. Thus it should be possible to reach a higher total throughput than you have. See [benchmarks from libreswan](https://libreswan.org/wiki/Benchmarking_and_Performance_testing) where they reach several Gbit/s throughput when tested with iperf. You will also see in these benchmarks that the possible throughput highly depends on the cipher in use.

Comment: „You will also notice that the possible throughput highly depends on the cipher in use.¯ +1 absolutely !

Comment: So is there any parallel implementation of some good cypher inside ipsec? :P

Comment: @IjazKhan: to quote myself "I don't think that current implementations will encrypt data from the same data stream (connection) in parallel"